# Eclipse - Maven project changing source compliance

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a mid-size project in java eclipse, in which all dependencies were being manually imported into the build path. For the sake of sanity, I wanted to convert it to a maven project.

The problem is: I had the source level/jre defined for 1.8 and when i converted to a maven project, It switched to the default of 1.5.

I tried some answers around SO for forcing the source compliance in maven to 1.8 but it didn't work.

I added to the

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>[project group id]</groupId>
        <artifactId>[project artifact id]</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Is anything missing here?

EDIT1: Forget me, I'm bad. The correct version is:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

after this you need these two

- preference - > java - > compiler - > 1.8 and language level to 8
- preference - > java -> installed JRE -> JDK 1.8